# Add File Extension in TimedRotatingFileHandler

Tags: python, python-logging

I am trying to implement the python logging using **TimedRotatingFileHandler**

i'm getting the problem in adding the file extension in log filename

here is my code

```
Path(".\\Log").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
LOGGING_MSG_FORMAT  = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
LOGGING_DATE_FORMAT = '%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
formatter = logging.Formatter(LOGGING_MSG_FORMAT, LOGGING_DATE_FORMAT)
handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(".\\Log\\info.log",'midnight',1)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.addHandler(handler)
```

using this code very first time i'm getting the fileName "info.log" as expected, but when it rolls over to midnight
the fileName i'm getting is "info.log.2020-05-22" but what i'm expecting is "info.2020-05-22.log".

How i can append the handler suffix before to file extension(.log)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use a custom [`namer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.BaseRotatingHandler.namer):

```
handler.namer = lambda name: name + ".log"
```

Unfortunately, the namer function gets the processed name. The name param would be like `"info.log.2020-05-22"`, so you'll end up with `"info.log.2020-05-22.log"`. If double `.log` is not acceptable just remove the initial one:

```
handler.namer = lambda name: name.replace(".log", "") + ".log"
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks RafaIS That worked great for me. I just made one small change. I just removed the .log from the initial file.

`handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(".\\Log\\info",'midnight',1)`

then used the first lambda option:
`handler.namer = lambda name: name + ".log"`